# How to use IntStream in java 8 to return an ascending arraylist?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am quite fresh to the IntStream, now assume I have an Arraylist preserved some entities:

```
  public ArrayList<Entity> entities(){return entities;}
  ArrayList<Entity> entities=new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I created a subclass rock which has x, y, and radius as fields:

```
record Rock(int x,int y,int radius) implements Entity{
  //Some method
  }
```

Now I want to return the rock which radius ordered from big to small:

```
  OptionalInt findRock(ArrayList<Entity> es){
    //This one returns the rock in a stored order, but I want get the rock sequence from big radius to small radius
    return IntStream.range(0,es.size()).filter(i->es.get(i) instanceof Rock).findFirst();    
    }
```

For example, if I have `rock1 which radius == 15`, `rock2 which radius == 10`, `rock3 which radius == 20`, it will return `rock3 -> rock1 -> rock2`

Is there any way to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use IntStream to sorted, stream directly on the list. But if the list doesn't only contains Rock, how do you do ?

Comment: Don't you use anything to sort ? And want a list sorted or just a Rock instance having max radius ?

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this

```
entities.stream()
        .filter(Rock.class::isInstance)
        .map(Rock.class::cast)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Rock::getRadius))
        .forEach(rock -> System.out.println("Rock with radius " + rock.getRadius()));
```

Use `Comparator.comparing(Rock::getRadius).reversed()` if you want the opposite order. You don't need an `IntStream`.

Comment: You can use `Comparator.comparingInt` to avoid boxing